# Java Using iterator for arraylist how do you get index

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

If i'm using Iterator how do i get the index in which my condition is met?  `iterator.next()` gives me one after so I can minus one but I figure this is right way to do this?

```
public static int getSomething()
    int tempposition = 1;
            Iterator<Item> iterator = data.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {
                if (iterator.next().getTitle().equals("Something"))
                {
                    tempposition = iterator.next().getPosition();
                }


            }

return tempposition - 1;
```

What I found to be correct code for my situation.

```
public static int getSomething()
    {
        int tempposition = 1;

        Iterator<Item> iterator = data.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
          Item item = iterator.next();

              if (item.getTitle().equals("Something"))
            {
                tempposition = item.getPosition();
            }

        }


        Log.d(TAG, "tempposition is " + tempposition );
        return tempposition ;


    }
```

Comment: If you want index, then why not just use the old traditional `for` loop?

Comment: @MAXGEN An iterator should be general enough to be used across many containers, some of which do not necessarily have a useful "index" semantics (e.g. a set, etc). So, if you want index, you'd want a lower level abstraction (plain ol' `for` loop, etc).

Comment: Definitely could do that, is there way for the Iterator or am I missing something that I don't understand about it?  Essentially aren't they the same thing?

Comment: @Santa okay then I guess that answers that. But am I right about taking one away because of the next() command is giving me one pass one I need?

Comment: @MAXGEN As @assylias pointed out, the extra index might be because you called `.next()` twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably get an unexpected value for `tempposition` because you call `next` twice in your loop. It should probably look like this instead:

```
Item item = iterator.next(); // call next only once here
if (item.getTitle().equals("Something")) {
    tempposition = item.getPosition();
}
```

Comment: Is SomeObject O the same as "Iterator<Item> iterator"? This is problem i'm running into wit your method.  I have custom arraylist not a generic string.

Comment: What does iterator resolved to?  Iterator<Item> iterator = null ; This is what suggested by eclipse debug?  But this method crashes.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your help. Posting the finish code above.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm

> `int nextIndex()`
>       Returns the index of the next element. If there is not a next element, returns the size of the list.
>       int `previousIndex()`
>       Returns the index of the previous element. If there is not a previous element, returns `-1`.

Comment: Thanks the link help!  Somewhat limited for index calls.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track yourself

```
public static int getSomething()
    int tempposition = 1;
    int index = 0;
            Iterator<Item> iterator = data.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {
                if (iterator.next().getTitle().equals("Something"))
                {
                    tempposition = iterator.next().getPosition();
                }
                index++;


            }

return tempposition - 1;
```